# Unable to install Ubuntu on second drive dedicated partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I want to install Ubuntu on my PC's second drive, but since it has already data on it i've decided to create a dedicated partition of it.

This is how my disk manager shows the disks' partitioning:

[image: Disk partitioning]

However, once in the Ubuntu installer it just won't show the partition as free space, in fact it won't show the partition at all

Comment: There is only one partition on the second drive. You need to create a new partition (using the Ubuntu installer) in the unallocated space and set it as `/` mount point.

Comment: If Windows fast start up is on, All NTFS partitions are hibernated & Linux driver will not see them correctly. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions  It looks like drives are MBR partitioned, so only use Something Else install option and be sure to install grub2's boot loader to MBR of sdb drive. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Installing_Ubuntu_to_a_Specific_Partition_.28.22Something_Else.22.29

Comment: Fast startup was already off, the problem is that the Ubuntu installer sees the second drive as unpartitioned, so there is no unallocated space

Comment: When in the installer, can you go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and typing `parted --list` and [edit]ing that into your question and leave a comment @Fabby

Comment: @Fabby It won't let me, it says either that I don't have permission or that it's an invalid token

Comment: @Fabby however I was able to get to GParted and it showed that Ubuntu was unable to detect the file system of my second drive...

Comment: `sudo parted --list`